# Why am I getting the "No namespaces to :aot compile listed in project.clj." warning?

Tags: clojure

I am using lein 1.6.2 on Ubuntu 1.04, and have created a bare project. I can't figure out why I'm getting the

"No namespaces to :aot compile listed in project.clj."

error when I enter lien compile.

project.clj

```
(defproject amr_db "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                [korma "0.2.1"]])
```

core.clj (so far)

```
(ns amr_db.core
  (:gen-class))
```

How do I clear the warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add a line like this to your project.clj

```
:main amr_db.core
```

you may also want something like this if the compiled jars are not main.

```
:aot [amr_db.core amr_db.another_example]
```

Comment: Many thanks. I had searched for something like this, and only found you don't need to aot compile, not how to do it. Thanks again.

Comment: what does "if the compiled jars are not main" mean here?